# How can I return stdin to the console?

Tags: c, stdio

I may be missing something here, but is it possible to change `stdin` to be a file pointer and then switch it back to the console?

Example:

```
stdin = fp;
for (int x; x < 10; x++)
{
   c = getchar()
}
stdin = ??? // Return the stream to the console
```

Comment: Technically yes, but I feel this is an XY problem. What is the underlying problem you’re trying to solve here? Might be much easier to just read from a stream and assign either a file or stdin as the stream.

Comment: Why not `c = getc(fp);` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "official" answer is `freopen()`.  Theoretically you can call

```
freopen("somefile", "r", stdin);
```

and now `stdin` is reading from `"somefile"`.  However, once you've done this it's either tricky or impossible to get `stdin` pointing back at standard input (or, as you called it, "the console") when you're done.  See also questions [12.33](http://c-faq.com/stdio/freopen.html) and [12.34](http://c-faq.com/stdio/undofreopen.html) in the old [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).

But really: why are you trying to reassign `stdin` in this way?  `stdin` is basically a global variable, and any time you have the pattern

```
change global variable;
make function call that implicitly uses global variable;
set global variable back to what it was;
```

you have poor design and a recipe for disaster.  Usually what you want to do is to create a modified version of that function call in the middle -- whatever it is -- that lets you pass the something in *as an explicit parameter*, rather than implicitly using the global variable.

In this case, you don't even need to invent anything new, because instead of `getchar()` which implicitly reads from the global `stdin`, you can just call `getc(fp)`, which reads from whatever file pointer you want to specify:

```
for (int x; x < 10; x++)
{
   c = getc(fp);
}
```

Comment: If you're willing to assume that stdin was previously connected to the terminal, on Linux you can use `freopen("/dev/tty", "r", stdin);`

Comment: yeah, it is bad indeed, I was really sleepy when I was designing the code, and got dragged in figuring out a way to reset stdin, rather than coming up with a better design, still, beneficial answer nonetheless.

Answer (score -1):

Save it in another variable first.

```
FILE *save_stdin = stdin;
stdin = fp;
...
stdin = save_stdin;
```

Of course, there may be no need to change `stdin` in the first case. You could just use `getc(fp)` instead of `getchar()`. Reassigning `stdin` would only be necessary if you're calling code that uses `stdin` and can't be changed.

Comment: Assigning to `stdin` is not guaranteed to be supported. The `freopen` function can be used to make `stdin` read from a file.

Comment: Good point, but in that case there's no way to restore it, because there's no filename for the original stdin, so you can't use `freopen()` to go back.

Comment: ...which, I guess, is why Linux invented that filename: `/proc/$$/fd/0`.  (I think I've also seen symlinks `/proc/$$/stdin`.)

Comment: @SteveSummit: `/dev/fd/0` is also commonly available, but since `freopen` "first attempts to close any file that is associated with the specified stream", by the time you come to reinstate the original stream, file descriptor 0 may no longer exist, or it may refer to a different file altogether by that time. You'd probably have to `dup()` fd 0 before the first call to `freopen`, keep open the returned descriptor, and use the special file for that descriptor in the restoring `freopen` call.

Comment: @Crowman Cripes, you're right about the closing.  I've mucked around with `dup()`, and `dup2()`, too, but things rapidly degenerate into a bad bowl of spaghetti, so I didn't even mention those.

Answer (score -1):

According to the `man stdin`:

> Since the symbols stdin, stdout, and stderr are specified to be
> macros, assigning to them is nonportable.  The standard streams can be
> made to refer to different files with help of the library function
> freopen, specially introduced to make it possible to reassign stdin,
> stdout, and stderr.

So, it is not safe to do that.
But, you can use fdopen with input stream file descriptor and reading mode to recover stdin as following:

```
stdin = fdopen(0, "r");
```

In the following code, the first loop reads the data from the file example, and the second loop reads characters from the standard input:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("example.txt", "r");

char c;
stdin = fp;
while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
    printf("%c", c);
}    

stdin = fdopen(0, "r");
while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
    printf("%c", c);
}

fclose(fp);
return 0;
```

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. If assigning to `stdin` is allowed, then you gain nothing by using `fdopen`, and it makes more sense to just store and re-assign the original value. Also, repeated use of this method in this answer will leak resources, since every execution of `stdin = fp;` will lose your only reference to the memory that was allocated on your previous call to `fdopen`.

Comment: You're right. I won't delete my post to learn from our mistakes.